# how to download jwplayer streaming video?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, jwplayer

i subscribe to [drupalize.me](http://drupalize.me) .but due to my slow internet connection i am not able to see video tutorials properly.i think this site use jwplayer and site provide no downloading option for videos.can anyone tell how to find direct downloading link of streaming video? if anyone give direct downloading link of drupalize.me [free sample video](http://drupalize.me/videos/fantasy-site-stack-overflow-diwd-09) it will be great.please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [way](http://nickolaszev.blogspot.com/2011/12/download-streamedflash-videos-from-jw.html) that works for me. 
In an addition I removed `-a vod` option because it caused an error.

Comment: rtmpExplorer (GUI for rtmpdump) is just awesome. It allowed me to paste the url of main page and gave the option to download the video directly!!!

Answer (score -2):

Real player has a browser plugin that does that, (works well only in IE)
Also IDM (internet download manager) does the same (again IE only) I've disable both plugins on chrome after having problems with it.
http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xY_7HRgsw8g

Real Player is free IDM is not (other than the cracked versions on torrent ;) )

IDM allows to select what video stream to download 
(if you change resolution on youtube, you'll see 2 files for download, 1 for each resolution)